# Calculate expected Voltage at a distant electrode

Tags: electricity, electric-fields

Firstly, please forgive me for misconceptions and errors as my knowledge of Physics is very basic.

I have EEG data (uV vs time) traces for an array of platinum electrodes placed on the surface of the brain. Two of the electrodes from the array are used to perform a bipolar stimulation while the others are set to record voltage.

I would like to calculate the expected voltage recorded in each electrode due to volume conduction of electricity through the brain medium (i.e. non-physiological electrical activity), due to the bipolar stimulation.

I know that the bipolar stimulation creates an electric field and I have a feeling the voltage recorded at a distant site would be inversely related to both distance and brain medium impedance.

Does anyone know what additional information I would need to calculate this?

In the literature there are reports for various electrical properties of brain medium (resistance, conductivity, permitivity etc.) using various stimulation parameters (frequency, current amplitude etc). My stimulations last 500us, are 4mA, and are biphasic (the anode and cathode switch after 500us and the stimulation is repeated). I stimulate approximately once every 5 seconds, so this is a low frequency stimulation.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is, unfortunately, more complicated than you would like.  The good news is, that you can start with Maxwell's equations and you can set everything with a B or an H to zero, because magnetic fields do not matter in this case. This allows us to treat the entire problem as a potential problem with one scalar potential, where

$E=\nabla\phi$.

Maxwell's equations reduce to two coupled equations

$\nabla E = \rho/\epsilon$ and

$\epsilon\partial{E}/\partial{t}=-J$.

You can substitute the $E$ field by the gradient of the potential in these equations and then you get an inhomogeneous  Laplace equation for the potential. The real problem is, that for your problem $\epsilon$ is not constant (and can be quite high for skin, depending on the preparation of the electrode surface) and the charge density $\rho$ and current $J$ are both made up of multiple components. Beyond electrons you would also have to take the ionic species of Na and K into account, which is further complicated by the fact that human tissue uses active pump mechanisms for these ions. The only way to model this correctly is to make assumptions about the electrical characteristics of tissue and to numerically solve the equations for a complex three dimensional model of the human skull with brain tissue, surrounding liquid, bone and skin layers. That's can be a rather tough problem, depending on the level of detail that you are interested in.

The better way, in my opinion, is to use a similar biological system (pig's head?) and to measure the potentials "in-vivo" (the pig would be dead, of course). That way you will get real data quickly and there won't be any guessing about the assumptions of your calculations.

Comment: Many thanks, this seems like a great starting point. For the Maxwell's equations, is the gradient of the potential the difference in voltage between the bipolar electrodes, with respect to distance? 

Re: ionic species of Na and K- I suppose this would be taken into account in the electrical characteristics of tissue from the literature.

I have actually done an experiment using some brain-like Gel. I'm interested in characterising voltage vs. distance due to volume conduction of the stimulus. My results do not look informative, hence trying to find out what would be expected theoretically.

Comment: The voltage between the electrodes is the difference between the potentials. For homogeneous conductive media the solutions to the time-independent Laplace equation are pretty boring. In your case the interesting physics lies in the layering of the media, i.e. in the skin effect and the time dependence of the solution. How much you could get out of such a calculation depends on the trouble you are willing to go trough to model the details. My suggestion to do this experimentally was meant to point out that theory is only useful if you have measurements to compare it to.

Comment: Thanks. The electrodes actually lie on the brain surface (under the dura), though there would still be layers of different permittivity. I found a paper that did something similar to what you suggested, in 1993 (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/001346949390006H), using finite element modelling. I could potentially do this. Could I also use Coloumbs Law by itself for a homogenous permittivity medium, if I know the permittivity of medium and voltages of stimulation? I guess I would integrate the Volts per metre calculated from the E field across the electrode surface?

Comment: I did realise - the E field would last ~1 millisecond (see earlier description), while my data is 512Hz (sample every ~2ms), hence I could not study the electric field directly, and anything observed would be more related to effects such as electrode capacitance and 'ringing'? But, this stuff is all really useful and interesting, it will go in my thesis :)

Answer (score 0):

Grin, Let me start with an old [physics joke.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow)

So I have no idea, but I might start by treating the brain as a spherical ball filled with salty water, and then ask how the currents will flow, and that would give me a first guess.  (Maybe not a very good one.)

I just measured the conductivity of water, see my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/134634/using-a-bottle-of-water-as-a-resistor/134638?noredirect=1#comment271798_134638).

Do you really push 4mA through the brain?  What's the voltage?
Will you see electrolysis effects in the brain??

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for that.

It is 4mA between electrodes that are 10 mm apart.

The voltage data may be available, although I currently do not have that information available.

I am not sure if electrolysis effects are seen, do you think this is important?

Comment: Re Electrolysis? Ahh, no, I'm a novice and have no idea.  (I think electrolysis will only happen at the electrodes.)  It's only that I recently discovered that it is the reason  you can't measure the conductivity of water at DC.  With only 10mm separation maybe model the sphere as a semi-infinite conductor.  That would be easier.  Those who characterize semiconductor's have models for how the current flows when you just have point contact type inputs.    Search for "collinear four point probe"

Comment: @cris, Just reading about four point probes in an electronics book and discovered that the technique was taken from geophysics where it was used to measure the earths resistivity.. there it is called  Wenner's Method.

Comment: thanks. The four point probe looks like a similar problem. If I can extract the resistance value from the literature, I guess I could theoretically predict the voltage recorded at one of the 'V' probes using Ohms Law as I know the applied current? However, the bipolar, biphasic stimulation is always between two adjacent electrodes on the array (which is e.g. 6 x 8 electrodes), so no there are no recording electrodes in between, as with the four point probe method. I'm doing further reading into whether the principles can be helpful.